# how to report on an object's fields in Salesforce

Tags: reporting, fields, configuration

Seems like a basic question but from a "describing a configuration" perspective is there a way of reporting on the fields in Salesforce so that the report can be exported to something like a spreadsheet showing the field name, format, object it belongs to, whether it is used etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

There's no "direct" way to report on metadata, but one handy tool you could look at is [Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4). It's free, and does a pretty good job of not just cataloging fields and objects, but can even give you an idea of the utilization of these fields. You could, of course, write your own tool instead, describing all the objects, then the fields.